# How to write an SQL query to fetch the id in a column that has all the required data in some other column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose I have the following table,

```
+---------+------------+
|   id    |    names   |
+---------+------------+
|   1     |      a     |
|   1     |      b     |
|   1     |      c     |
|   1     |      d     |
|   2     |      b     |
|   3     |      a     |
|   3     |      b     |
|   3     |      c     |
|   4     |      c     |
+---------+------------+
```

I want to fetch the id using SQL query, which has all the names "a", "b", and "c".

Here the answer would be 1 and 3.

Please edit the title more suitable for the question above.

Answer (score 3):

Using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT names)`, you can get the expected result:

```
SELECT id
FROM TableName
WHERE names IN ('a', 'b', 'c')  
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT names) = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group by` and `having`.  Assuming no duplicates:

```
select id
from t
where names in ('a', 'b', 'c')
group by id
having count(*) = 3;
```

If duplicates are permitted, use:

```
having count(distinct name) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will better solve the problem

```
SELECT * from (SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT( TRIM(names) ORDER BY names  SEPARATOR',') agg_name FROM table GROUP BY id)A where A.agg_name = 'a,b,c';
```

Comment: In case if the data are stored in the order of `b`, `c` and `a`, it will not work.

Comment: thanks for the catch...! Modified, please review

Comment: this assumes tables are stored in a order or resultset are fetched in a order  like @Arulkumar already said ... ANSI/ISO standard SQL has defined SQL tables/results are **orderless** without using `ORDER BY` ..  Also adding `ORDER BY id` wil not help as the results are still be non deterministic (random) as the values are not unique.with that column.   edit: i just noticed a answer edit it was last refreshing/updating here

Comment: *"! Modified, please review"* with small groups and or small values this might work for larger data requirements this will most likely fail or not work as expected as `GROUP_CONCAT()` has a default limit of 1024 after that it simply truncates without a error, but you can increase the value.

Comment: I hope for this specific case this will work as..! and it will be fastest solutions as we aren't performing group conditioning..

Comment: *"and it will be fastest solutions as we aren't performing group conditioning."* that is a bold statement to make without benchmarking, i did a few tests and Arulkumar/Gordon Linoff approach is 95 to 100% of the reloads faster with or without indexes as the string concat is more CPU/Memory expensive which will be even more noticable the more records the table has ... Also your query is incorrect written as it is as it should be `LIKE '%a,b,c%';`

Comment: "it will be fastest solutions as we aren't performing group conditioning" - I don't think so. Without the WHERE condition the query has to read and group the entire table, instead of reading only rows with `a`, `b` and `c`. And it is also wrong, since id=1 won't be returned, because it also has `'d'` in `names`.